# Expected standard deviation of probabilistic sample

Tags: probability, standard-deviation, expected-value, sample

Let's say I have a collection of $n$ individuals, each individual is associated with a single value $x_i$, with $i = 1, 2, 3, ... n$. I now gather a sample of $s$ individuals from this collection, without replacement. $s > 1$. Each individual has a certain probability $p_i$ of being included in my sample, and I know this probability. My sample of $s$ individuals will have a certain standard deviation with respect to $x$.

My question: is there a way to calculate the expected standard deviation of $x$ of my sample, given: all individuals' values $x$, all individual's probabilities $p$, and my sample size $s$? If I were to randomly draw my sample infinitely many times, what would the average sample standard deviation be?

Comment: https://newonlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat506/node/16/

Comment: As far as I understand, the notes on the Horvitz-Thompson estimator (and Hansen, Hurwitz for cases with replacement) give me the variance of my total estimate/mean estimate, over samples. I am looking for the expected variance within my samples.

Comment: Your "collection" is the *population.*  This is a direct application of the HT estimator to that population with your given inclusion probabilities.